# Looking for a browser reflow benchmark

Tags: browser, benchmarking, reflow

I work on a embeded opera implementation and want to test the real performance. I have done the sunspider js benchmark and want to know the html/css performance now.

Are there any good reflow benchmarks for opera out there?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to check the performance of your website is by [validating](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) your css / html, often errors in your css / html cause "slow" performance.

I also found [this website](http://site-perf.com/), which lets you check the performance of your website. I have not tested this so I'm not sure if it a decent one.

Comment: thanks for the hint with valid html/css can change browser performance. your link isn't much of a help though. i need something that i can run on a embedded system. to check the reflow performance of opera on my embedded system.